# Add existing items of Sharepoint list to a folder programmatically

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I have about 20K items in a sharepoint 2010 list and I want to arrange every 5k items in a folder programmatically and also make sure that the newly added items are also in folder once they reach 5k limit.

I have not worked on creating folders in sharepoint programmatically. Can someone help me with a piece of code.

Answer (score 0):

For create folder in SPList use below sample code it will help you.

```
SPSite oSite = new SPSite("http://localhost/");
SPWeb oWeb = oSite.OpenWeb();
//Provide SPList name which you use...
SPList oList = oWeb.Lists["testlist"];
oWeb.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
//Add a Folder as List Item in SPList as below
SPListItem folderItem = oList.Items.Add(oList.RootFolder.ServerRelativeUrl, SPFileSystemObjectType.Folder);            
//Add Folder Title here
folderItem["Title"] = "1-5000-Items-Folder";
folderItem.Update();

oWeb.AllowUnsafeUpdates = false;
```

Comment: Please don't use signatures on StackOverflow - http://stackoverflow.com/faq#signatures

Answer (score 0):

For create folder in SPList use below sample code it will help you.

```
SPSite oSite = new SPSite("http://localhost/");
SPWeb oWeb = oSite.OpenWeb();
//Provide SPList name which you use... 
SPList oList = oWeb.Lists["testlist"]; 
oWeb.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true; 
//Add a Folder as List Item in SPList as below 
SPListItem folderItem = oList.Items.Add(oList.RootFolder.ServerRelativeUrl, SPFileSystemObjectType.Folder);             
//Add Folder Title here folderItem["Title"] = "1-5000-Items-Folder"; 
folderItem.Update();  
oWeb.AllowUnsafeUpdates = false;
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use CAML query to loop folder in SP. Also never use list.Items.Add() instead use listitems.add().

Use the code while finding a folder :

```
SPQuery query = new SPQuery(); 
query.Query = "<Where><And><Eq><FieldRef  Name='LinkTitle'/><Value Type='Text'>" +folderName + "</Value></Eq><Eq><FieldRef   Name='FSObjType'/><Value Type='Lookup'>1</Value></Eq></And></Where>";query.ViewAttributes = "Scope=\"RecursiveAll\"";  
SPListItemCollection items = list.GetItems(query);
if (items.Count == 0){Create a folder}
else{
SPListItem listItem = list.AddItem(folderItem.Folder.ServerRelativeUrl,SPFileSystemObjectType.File, null);}
```